# Unable to install quickly in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: installation, ubuntu-18.04

Installing quickly on Ubuntu 18.04

```
$ sudo apt-get install quickly quickly-ubuntu-template

Reading package lists... Done 
Building dependency tree      
Reading state information... Done 
E: Unable to locate package quickly-ubuntu-template
```

Build new apps quickly - is not found in the Ubuntu Software Center also.

How can I now install quickly?

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid after Ubuntu 14.04 Quickly is no longer available for download but you could use illumination software creator from :
https://github.com/jsebean/IlluminationSoftwareCreator
but i haven't found how to install it yet...